# $f(\frac{1}{n})=1$ for all positive integers $n$. Prove that $f'(0)=0$ and hence prove that $f''(0)=0$

Tags: analysis, implicit-differentiation

$f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function double differentiable throughout.$f(\frac{1}{n})=1$ for all positive integers $n$.
Prove that $f'(0)=0$ and hence prove that $f''(0)=0$

My take:
We know $f'(0)= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } n(1-f(0))$
From here I don't know how to proceed from here.
Please help

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $0$, it is continuous at $0$. What does this tell you about $f(0)$?

Comment: So, continuity at $0$ gives $f(0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(0+h)$ Take $h=1/n$ .$f(0)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(\frac{1}{n})=1$ Does this imply $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: Use the mean value theorem and continuity of $f'$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is twice differentiable then $f$ is continuous.  We have immediately $f(0)=1$ since $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(1/n)=f(0)=1$.

---

From the mean value theorem, there exists $\xi_n\in (0,1/n)$ such that

$$f'(\xi_n)=\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{ \frac1n} =0$$

Since $f$ is twice differentiable, the $f'$ is continuous and we have

$$0=\lim_{n\to \infty}f'(\xi_n)=f'(0)$$

as was to be shown.

---

From the mean value theorem, there exists $\eta_n\in (-1/n,0)$ such that

$$f(-1/n)=1-\frac1n f'(\eta_n)$$

Finally, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(1/n)-2f(0)+f(-1/n)}{1/n^2}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1)-2(1)+\left(1-\frac1n f'(\eta_n)\right)}{1/n^2}\\\\
&=- \lim_{n\to \infty}nf'(\eta_n)\\\\
\end{align}$$

But using Taylor's Theorem with the Peano form of the remainder, $f'(\eta_n)=o(\eta_n)$, which implies that $nf'(\eta_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Hence, we find $f''(0)=0$ as was to be shown!.

Comment: Why is that $f(-1/n) = 1$?

Comment: @JohnMa It isn't.  I've added more details.  Much appreciate your pointing out the ambiguity.  -Mark

Comment: Another way to show $f''(0)=0:$ Taylor gives $f(x) = 1 + f''(0)x^2/2 +o(x^2).$

Comment: @zhw. I love the Peano man!

Comment: @MarkViola $f''(x)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$ So it should be $\frac{1}{n^2}$ in the denominator instead of $\frac{2}{n}$, which completely changes the solution.

Comment: @SufaidSaleel Thank you for the catch.  I've corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?
Since,$f$ is differentiable at $x=0$,
$$f'(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ f(\frac 1n)-f(0) }{\frac 1n} =0$$.
Now by Taylor's theorem we have, $f(\frac 1n)=f(0)+f'(0)\cdot \frac 1n +f''(c_n)\cdot \frac{1}{2n^2}$
$\implies f''(c_n)=0$ where $c_n\in (0,\frac 1n)$
As $n\to \infty$,$c_n \to 0$.
So, $f''(0)=0$.(I think here we needed an extra assumption that f'' is continuous). Do you have any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: We don't need continuity of $f''$.  I've posted a way forward that relies on Taylor's Theorem with the Peano form of the remainder.